# Androidでマイナー言語（ラオス語）を写真に撮って、文字認識をさせたい。

Tags: android, opencv

お世話になります。

現在Androidアプリ（4.2～）を開発中なのですが、将来の機能として、
ラオス語の看板や、メニューを写真に撮って翻訳を表示させる機能を実装したいと思っています。

ですが、文字認識や、機械学習の知識がなくどこからどう初めて良いか分かりません。
OpenCV3.0でJavaがサポートされ、機能として機械学習も利用できると聞いたので、
OpenCVを利用すれば何とかなるのではと思っているのですが、手掛かりがありません。

そもそも前提知識が必要ということならどの本で学べばよいか、またすでに同じようなことをされている方がいて情報が公開されているならそれを教えていただけないでしょうか？

ちなみに、OpenCVで利用可能な文字認識のパッケージ？はラオス語のものは存在してないみたいです。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ラオ文字については後述します。

まず文字認識といえばTesseract OCRと思ったのでググるとOpenCV3.0から使える文字認識のもこれっぽいですね。
http://whoopsidaisies.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/11/12/003100
http://independence-sys.net/main/?p=1831
この辺が参考になるでしょうか。
なお、OpenCVは前処理にしか使われていませんが、androidの文字認識アプリの参考として以下とかどうでしょう？
http://www.slideshare.net/youheiyamaguchi/ss-12902286
さらにアルゴリズム的な所は以下とか。
http://www.slideshare.net/levelfour/shrift

肝心のラオ文字の文字認識についてですが、Tesseractの場合、なければ作れます。
http://hadashi-gensan.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/15/135316
http://www.slideshare.net/takmin/tesseract-ocr
まあ、この学習データの良し悪しが精度は精度に効いてくるのでなかなか大変だとは思いますが、文字種が少ないのでそれなりのものが得られるのではないでしょうか。
ついでにandroidでのTesseractとか。
http://qiita.com/Nunocky/items/17df047a2a945d7a0a14
http://tech.jsa.co.jp/tess-two_2_how_to_recognize/

Comment: Tesseractは手順を踏めば自作できるんですね？！
それが知れただけでも大きな前進です！

ラオス語は確かに文字種が少ないので、日本語のような絶望的なことはなさそうです。ただ、文字の組み合わせで、ひとまとまりになったりするのでそのあたり注意してやってみます。
良い：ດີ　＝ດ＋ ີ 

ありがとうございました！